# Remove Brackets from Variable (CLI-Windows)

Tags: string, batch-file, command-line-interface

Based on the code below, the output of Var is (COM19). I was wandering what command can be used to remove the brackets? Tried using sed, but would ideally want a solution that doesn't not require additional installations on Windows.

```
@echo off
setlocal

wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:list > output.txt
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('find /i "USB Serial Port" output.txt') do set var=%%a

pause

goto :EOF
```

Comment: "Tried using sed, but would ideally want a solution that doesn't not require additional installations". This implies you are running Windows. Is that correct? That might help others deciding on the tools that you do have.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I am using windows

Comment: `::` is a label command with a name of `:` as `:` specifies a label. So no command on lines starting `::` will run.

Comment: I am aware of this. the codes in question are commented out on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue ussing the delims, in line with the token function. Code can be seen below.

```
@echo off
setlocal

wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:list > output.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('find /i "USB Serial Port" output.txt') do set var=%%a

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=()" %%a in ("%output%") do (echo %%a)
```

Comment: output is not a variable, but a text file. Will the above code still work, if "%output%" is replaced with output.txt?

Comment: yes. you can do the syntax like this `for /f "usebackq delims=()" %%a in ("path+output.txt") do @(echo %%a)`

Comment: I tried adding your command as seen below to my code by seem to get an error when executing `for /f "delims=()" %%a in ('%var%') do (echo %%a)`

Comment: In `for` syntax, you have to use `""` without `usebackq` or `''` with `usebackq` to quote the variable. you can do `for /?` to see the detail. Your `%var%` is a variable, not a file.

Comment: Your updated one can be combined in one syntax  `for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:list^|find /i "USB Serial Port"') do set var=%%a`. So no need to create output.txt.